# How does a new user know that there are lots of FAQ questions on meta?

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

I know that we have all these wonderful [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tagged questions, but as has been commented elsewhere, MSO gets about 0.6% of the traffic of SO ... so really this is like us patting ourselves on the back and documenting things for the die hards. I feel like this is a really valuable set of resources that we do keep up with, and that it's not super-beneficial if nobody sees it.

How do the people who would probably benefit from this stuff in the long run find these posts other than us regulars bumping into people and giving them a link to a FAQ? (nevermind, it's on the very bottom of the FAQ page on SO)

How can we make it more prominent? Or do we need to?

Comment: Yes!  We need more prominence!

Comment: According to the SO FAQ, people should only read the MSO FAQ if "you’re looking for _excruciating_ detail."  OH, THE PAIN.  At least it could be **deliciously** excruciating.  :-)

Comment: Well, there's a [faq](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=faq) tab in the [Questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) view.  It's pretty easy to find.

Comment: @RobertHarvey which requires them to be on MSO in the first place, thus negating my point.

Comment: @Robert: Never saw that before! It would be nice if it also appeared on the home page.

Comment: @jcolebrand: There's a meta link right at the very top of SO. That's about as prominent as it gets.  Anyway, the real problem is not that people can't find this information, it's that *people don't read.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey ~ So I should post a followup question? _"How do I get people to read and think for themselves?"_ ... it _is_ relevant, but likely to get closed as NaRQ ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 0.6% exposure to the FAQ sounds about right. The truth is that the vast, vast, vast majority of **users really don't care** about this stuff.

The typical user arrives at a Stack Exchange site looking for the best answers; A few might vote up posts they find useful; Even fewer might ask their *own* question or contribute an answer of their own.

Way, way, way far down that list are users who will ever *care* what "flag weight" is, or want to know how to audit their reputation, or how the default user avatar is generated.

Stack Exchange is designed so most users really don't *have* to care about this stuff. The system pretty much takes care of itself, and the 0.6% of users who know about these "insider baseball" issues take care of the rest.

Trying to expose these <quote>Frequently</quote> Asked Questions to users who just want to go about the business of actually *using* the site would make the whole system seem too complicated and overwrought with process. On the rare occasion where users ask about these issues, the answers are here for them. There's no need to make it more prominent.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I'd be surprised if 0.6% of SO users get to the bottom of the SO FAQ, let alone following the link through to here.

And even then, they have to get through the unicorn barrier.