# Why are questions on meta.stackoverflow.com never displayed on the stackexchange.com home page?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, meta

The list of [hot questions](https://stackexchange.com/) doesn't include our beloved meta. My question is, why?

I think the visitors of stackexchange.com would be interested in changes and other discussion regarding the community they are using. Or, better put, the chance of them being interested is certainly higher than the chance they are interested in a SE website that can be about *anything*, from cooking to AI to music.

Obviously I'm only talking about this meta, the "central meta". Adding the metas of all the other sites would only create noise because they'll only talk about one specific website, not the entire network, so the likelihood of the user being interested is extremely small.

Comment: Good question, though as-is it's not a [feature-request] but a [discussion].  Changing it to "meta.stackoverflow.com questions should appear on the stackexchange.com homepage" would be a feature request.

Comment: @Daniel: it's more like a rhetorical question =)

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts to consider:

1. The number of users on the StackExchange network that are actually interested in the information on Meta is [relatively small](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93230/how-does-a-new-user-know-that-there-are-lots-of-faq-questions-on-meta/93311#93311).  Included in this elite group are the gearheads, the terminally pedantic, and people who like waffles.
2. When you are in the market for a new car, which is more important to you: the color of the paint, or the shape and size of the tools in the trunk?

Comment: For point 1: I agree that the number of users is small, but are you really saying that it's smaller than the amount of people interested in bicycles or german? Because both of those sites are on there.

Comment: For point 2: I'm not in the market for a new car, I don't think this analogy applies to how I use the hot question list. I'm in the market to kill time; I want something, anything to read useful or not, as long as it's interesting.

Comment: For point 1: To make it a fair comparison, you would have to compare german with german.meta, not german with all things meta.

Comment: I would also like to add that 3/4 of stack exchange websites have less visits than meta.

Comment: @Robert: why? Like I said I'm not interested in *what* or how *useful* it is; I just want something interesting. A thread on meta has the same if not more potential to be interesting as one in german.SE.

Comment: For point 2: You sound like my wife: "I have no interest in that, so I can't relate to your analogy."