# Discoverable links to Community FAQ posts in appropriate locations

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, meta-faq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does a new user know that there are lots of FAQ questions on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93230/how-does-a-new-user-know-that-there-are-lots-of-faq-questions-on-meta)

I, like others before me, have only recently discovered the [Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). And I, too, have wondered:

> "Wherefore had I not hitherto discovered this? Could not many of my fellow Stackizens enjoy these posts, and learn and benefit therefrom?"

Verily, the main FAQ has a minute link from the "What about…" section to the Community FAQ. But this is hardly obvious, and is unlikely to be found in a time of need.

And so I propose that there be subtle yet discoverable links on the main site leading to Community FAQ posts, enabling more in-depth learning for curious users. For example:

- A link from the [Badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) page to the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)
- Links from [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) to [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18584) and [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656), and others
- Links to [What is a "closed", “on hold”, or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) and other pages when a question is closed
- A link from revision history pages to [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)
- A link from [the FAQ section on reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) to [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: Related: [Why isn't the community FAQ more prominent?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65913/why-isnt-the-community-faq-more-prominent) -- Although I think maybe it has improved since Jeff answered that one.

Comment: Also see: [/faq HUHN! What is it good for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95224/faq-huhn-what-is-it-good-for) -- Yes, despite the title, I promise this one is actually relevant.

Comment: Yes, and I also saw http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96780/could-you-add-a-link-to-the-community-faq-to-the-faq. However, this is a more concrete suggestion for how to deal with the issue.